# On the regularity of Poisson's equation with Robin boundary condition

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, applications, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $u \in W^{1,2} (\Omega)$ be the weak solution to the following Poisson's equation with Robin Boundary condition.

\begin{equation}
-\Delta u= f \ \   \  \ \text{    in $\Omega$},\\
\frac{\partial u }{\partial \nu} + \tau u = \xi   \  \  \text{   on $ \partial \Omega$}.
\end{equation}

Here $\Omega$ is a smooth domain, $ f \in L^p (\Omega)$, for $ p \in [2, \infty)$. $\tau$ and $\xi$ are smooth functions on $\partial \Omega$ and $ \tau (x) \geq 0$ on $\partial \Omega$, but $\tau$ is not a zero function. Then can we say $u \in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$?

The book ''Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains'' by Grisvard says, $u \in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$, provided $\tau (x) > 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. But in the case of Grisvard,  the domain is non-smooth. But I am considering a smooth domain. So I hope the condition on $\tau $ can be generalized. Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: If it is true for non smooth domains it should be also true for smooth ones. Moreover, I think this condition is needed for the uniqueness of the solution.

Comment: I want $\tau$ to be non-negative, not just strictly positive.

Comment: If $\tau=0$, the solution is not unique. If $u$ is a solution, $u+\mathrm{const.}$ is also a solution.

Comment: $\tau$ is non-negative and not a zero function, this means $\tau$ must be positive at some points and some other points it can be zero.

Comment: Nonnegative doesn't mean that. The zero function is a nonnegative function.